# React Native: issue positioning two views with dinamic height

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

in my react native component I have a view that I want to give a kind of 3d effect shadow, for that I have a wrapper container with position relative, then inside this wrapper I have two absolute positioned views, I use the second one to give the shadow effect, positioning it directly behind the first one.

The first doesn't have a set height because of it's dynamic content, that's why I'm using onLayout to give the dynamic height to the wrapper and the other bottom "shadow" view, however it's not working and the views are not displaying correctly (they appear to have no height).

Image for reference.
https://i.imgur.com/MboV7lr.jpg

My code:

```
const [heightSegmentation, setHeightSegmentation] = useState(null);

const handleLayoutSegmentation = (event) => {
    const { height } = event.nativeEvent.layout;
    if (!heightSegmentation) {
        setHeightSegmentation(height);
    }
};

return (
    <View style={{ width: '100%', position: 'relative', marginVertical: 30 }}>
        <View 
            onLayout={handleLayoutSegmentation} 
            style={{ 
                zIndex: 9999, 
                position: 'absolute', 
                overflow: 'hidden', 
                padding: 15, 
                top: 0, 
                left: 0, 
                width: '97%', 
                flexDirection: 'column', 
                alignItems: 'center', 
                justifyContent: 'flex-start', 
                borderRadius: 10, 
                backgroundColor: 'white', 
                elevation: 8 
            }}
        >
            <Text 
                allowFontScaling={false} 
                style={{ 
                    fontSize: 16, 
                    color: root.mapStore.actionColor, 
                    position: 'relative', 
                    fontFamily: 'IBMPlexSans-Medium', 
                    fontWeight: '500' 
                }}
            >
                Google Ads
            </Text>
        </View>

        {heightSegmentation && (
            <View 
                style={{ 
                    height: heightSegmentation, 
                    zIndex: 999, 
                    position: 'absolute', 
                    top: 10, 
                    left: 10, 
                    width: '97%', 
                    flexDirection: 'row', 
                    alignItems: 'center', 
                    justifyContent: 'space-between', 
                    borderRadius: 10, 
                    backgroundColor: '#F37F06', 
                    elevation: 8 
                }}
            ></View>
        )}
    </View>
);
```

Comment: I have created an example (https://snack.expo.dev/@m.bahl/shadowed-view?platform=ios) based on your code. What is wrong with this?
I guess it might be that you are not using new Fabric system.

Comment: I'm not using Fabric